# Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process

Tags: java, android

Hello i tried in the past Week to implements Google sign in without Firebase.

I followed this steps of the Google stept by step introduction.

Everything worked fine but then i tried to compile and it gave me this Error:

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   Failed to process
>   C:\Users\Mike.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1.aar\5593e447f96dd34e42ee7b48f39c0a8c\jars\classes.jar

This is my gradle build and i tried everything
Thanks for to everyone who tried to help me

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    signingConfigs {
       //my key :D
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "smiets.justdontdie"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.justdontdiekey
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:25.0-android'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'


    }
```

Comment: try enabling multidex in your project. loo at the reference => https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Have you found a sollution? I am running into the same problem and multidex is already enabled in my project...